# How do I get a form element that is 600px when the window is wider than 600px?

Tags: html, css

I need to complete an html/css assessment as part of the admissions process of getting into a coding bootcamp. I submitted this code but I got feedback saying that I didn't have "a 'form' element that is 600px when the window is wider than 600px". I'm very confused as I clearly specified within the code that no element will exceed 600px regardless of screen size. I'm in a bit of a time crunch and have a limited amount of attempts at this assessment so any help would be appreciated.

```css
form {
  width: auto;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  /* big */
  .form {
      max-width: 600px;
      display: block;
      /* display: block;  is a maybe */
      grid-template-columns: 1fr;
      /* grid-template-columns: 1fr;  is also a maybe  */
    }

  label {
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: left;
    width: auto;
  }

  input,
  select,
  textarea {
    width: 100%;
  }

  .center {
    margin: auto;
    width: 50%;
    border: 3px;
  }

  .wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(1fr);
    gap: 12px;
  }

  .one {
    grid-row: 1;
    max-width: 600px;
  }

  .two {
    grid-row: 2;
    max-width: 600px;
  }

  .three {
    grid-row: 3;
    max-width: 600px; /*added later*/
  }

  .four {
    grid-row: 4;
    max-width: 600px;
  }

  .five {
    grid-row: 5;
    max-width: 600px;
  }

  .card {
    width: 344px;
    background-color: #E0E0E0;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 0;
  }

  .desertIm {
    height: 194px;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .title {
    color: #000;
    font-size: 22px;
  }

  .secondarytxt {
    color: #232F34;
  }

  .bodytxt {
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #232F34;
    margin: 16px;
  }

  .avatar {
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
    top: 20%;
    left: 15%;
  }
}


/* divider */

.item1 {
  grid-area: header;
} 
.item2 {
  grid-area: avatar;
}
.item3 {
  grid-area: sec;
}
.item4 {
  grid-area: title;
}
.item5 {
  grid-area: body;
}

.card {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    "header header header header header header"
    "avatar title title title title title"
    "avatar sec sec sec sec sec"
    "body body body body body body";
}

.card > div {
  text-align: left;
  background-color: white;
}

.card:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}

/* divider */

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  form {
    width: 100%;
  }

  label {
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: left;
    width: auto;
  }

  input,
  select,
  textarea {
    width: 100%;
  }

  .card {
    width: 344px;
    background-color: #E0E0E0;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 0;
  }

  .desertIm {
    height: 194px;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .title {
    color: #000;
    font-size: 22px;
  }

  .secondarytxt {
    color: #232f34;
  }

  .bodytxt {
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #232f34;
    margin: 16px;
  }

  .avatar {
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
    top: 20%;
    left: 15%;
  }

  .item1 {
    grid-area: header;
  } 
  .item2 {
    grid-area: avatar;
  }
  .item3 {
    grid-area: sec;
  }
  .item4 {
    grid-area: title;
  }
  .item5 {
    grid-area: body;
  }
  
  .card {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas:
      "header header header header header header"
      "avatar title title title title title"
      "avatar sec sec sec sec sec"
      "body body body body body body";
  }
  
  .card > div {
    text-align: left;
    background-color: white;
  }
  
  .card:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>

    <div class="center wrapper form">
      <form action="/pets" method="post">
      </form>


      <div class="one">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="pet_name">
      </div>

      <div class="two">
        <label for="type">Type
          <select name="pet_type" id="type">
            <option value="cat">Cat</option>
            <option value="dog">Dog</option>
            <option value="hamster">Hamster</option>
            <option value="other">Other</option>
            <option value="zebra">Zebra</option>
          </select>
        </label>
      </div>

      <div class="three">
        <label for="biography">Biography</label>
        <textarea id="bio" name="pet_bio" rows="4" cols="50">
        </textarea>
      </div>

      <div class="four">
        <label for="email">Owner's Email</label>
        <input type="email" id="owner-email" name="pet_owner_email">
      </div>

      <div class="five">
        <button type="submit" id="new-pet-submit-button">Create new pet</button>
        <button type="reset">Reset</button>
      </div>



     <!-- divider -->

      <div class="card">
        <div class="item1"><img src="images/desert.jpg" class ="desertIm"></div>
        <div class="item2"><img src="images/person-avatar.jpg" class="avatar"></div>
        <div class="item3"><body><p class="secondarytxt">Secondary text</p></body></div>  
        <div class="item4"><h4><b class="title">Title goes here</b></h4></div>
        <div class="item5"><body><p class="bodytxt">Greyhound divisively hello coldly
          wonderfully marginally far upon excluding.</p></body></div>
      </div>
    </div>  
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I can't see anything which has class form but you are specifying .form in the media query. Also, the form doesn't seem to be the parent of the inputs.

Comment: You should close form tag after all that divs and buttons.

Answer (score 0):

what you coded should be correct, when the screen exceeds 600px, the form stays at 600px

```css
form {
  width: 100%;
}
@media screen and (min-width: 600px) {
  /* big */
  .form {
      max-width: 600px;
      display: block;
      /* display: block;  is a maybe */
      grid-template-columns: 1fr;
      /* grid-template-columns: 1fr;  is also a maybe  */
    }

  label {
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: left;
    width: auto;
  }

  input,
  select,
  textarea {
    width: 100%;
  }

  .center {
    margin: auto;
    width: 50%;
    border: 3px;
  }

  .wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(1fr);
    gap: 12px;
  }

  .one {
    grid-row: 1;
    max-width: 600px;
  }

  .two {
    grid-row: 2;
    max-width: 600px;
  }

  .three {
    grid-row: 3;
    max-width: 600px; /*added later*/
  }

  .four {
    grid-row: 4;
    max-width: 600px;
  }

  .five {
    grid-row: 5;
    max-width: 600px;
  }

  .card {
    width: 344px;
    background-color: #E0E0E0;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 0;
  }

  .desertIm {
    height: 194px;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .title {
    color: #000;
    font-size: 22px;
  }

  .secondarytxt {
    color: #232F34;
  }

  .bodytxt {
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #232F34;
    margin: 16px;
  }

  .avatar {
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
    top: 20%;
    left: 15%;
  }
}


/* divider */

.item1 {
  grid-area: header;
} 
.item2 {
  grid-area: avatar;
}
.item3 {
  grid-area: sec;
}
.item4 {
  grid-area: title;
}
.item5 {
  grid-area: body;
}

.card {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    "header header header header header header"
    "avatar title title title title title"
    "avatar sec sec sec sec sec"
    "body body body body body body";
}

.card > div {
  text-align: left;
  background-color: white;
}

.card:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
}

/* divider */

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  form {
    width: 100%;
  }

  label {
    display: block;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: left;
    width: auto;
  }

  input,
  select,
  textarea {
    width: 100%;
  }

  .card {
    width: 344px;
    background-color: #E0E0E0;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 0;
  }

  .desertIm {
    height: 194px;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .title {
    color: #000;
    font-size: 22px;
  }

  .secondarytxt {
    color: #232f34;
  }

  .bodytxt {
    font-size: 11px;
    color: #232f34;
    margin: 16px;
  }

  .avatar {
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    position: relative;
    top: 20%;
    left: 15%;
  }

  .item1 {
    grid-area: header;
  } 
  .item2 {
    grid-area: avatar;
  }
  .item3 {
    grid-area: sec;
  }
  .item4 {
    grid-area: title;
  }
  .item5 {
    grid-area: body;
  }
  
  .card {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-areas:
      "header header header header header header"
      "avatar title title title title title"
      "avatar sec sec sec sec sec"
      "body body body body body body";
  }
  
  .card > div {
    text-align: left;
    background-color: white;
  }
  
  .card:hover {
    box-shadow: 0 2px 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  }
}
```

```html
<body>

  <div class="center wrapper form">
    <form action="/pets" method="post">
    </form>


    <div class="one">
      <label for="name">Name</label>
      <input type="text" id="name" name="pet_name">
    </div>

    <div class="two">
      <label for="type">Type
        <select name="pet_type" id="type">
          <option value="cat">Cat</option>
          <option value="dog">Dog</option>
          <option value="hamster">Hamster</option>
          <option value="other">Other</option>
          <option value="zebra">Zebra</option>
        </select>
      </label>
    </div>

    <div class="three">
      <label for="biography">Biography</label>
      <textarea id="bio" name="pet_bio" rows="4" cols="50">
      </textarea>
    </div>

    <div class="four">
      <label for="email">Owner's Email</label>
      <input type="email" id="owner-email" name="pet_owner_email">
    </div>

    <div class="five">
      <button type="submit" id="new-pet-submit-button">Create new pet</button>
      <button type="reset">Reset</button>
    </div>
    
    

   <!-- divider -->

    <div class="card">
      <div class="item1"><img src="images/desert.jpg" class ="desertIm"></div>
      <div class="item2"><img src="images/person-avatar.jpg" class="avatar"></div>
      <div class="item3"><body><p class="secondarytxt">Secondary text</p></body></div>  
      <div class="item4"><h4><b class="title">Title goes here</b></h4></div>
      <div class="item5"><body><p class="bodytxt">Greyhound divisively hello coldly
        wonderfully marginally far upon excluding.</p></body></div>
    </div>
  </div>  
</body>

</html>
```